# Reading mzXML (mass spectrometry) files in C#

Tags: c#, base64, endianness

I am trying to create a small application to read mass spectrometry data  from an mzXML file and draw a decently looking plot for potential publications, however I don't know how to read the actual data from the XML file.

As far as I know I need to decode it using Base64, decompress using bzip, convert from network to client byte order and finally produce some sort of array of doubles. I simply do not know enough about this aspect of programming to tranlate other online code snippets to C#.

Here is some code I fount online, but I simply can't translate it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Compress::Zlib qw(uncompress);
use MIME::Base64;

# Data is Base64 encoded and compressed with zlib
my $data = 'ENCODED DATA STRING';#keep encoded data here or read from file

# Decode and uncompress the data
my $base64decoded = uncompress( decode_base64($data) );

# Data is in 64-bit floats in network order
# Unpack as a 64-bit network order quad int
my @hostOrder = unpack("Q>*", $base64decoded );

#flag zero for m/z and 1 for intensity
my $flag=0; 

foreach my $i (@hostOrder) 
{
    # Pack into a native quad then unpack into the correct 64-bit float
    my $val = ( unpack("d", pack("Q", $i ) ) );

    if ($flag==0)
    {
        $val=sprintf("%.12g" , $val);
        print "$val ";
        $flag=1;
        next;
    }
    elsif($flag==1) 
    {
        if ($val==0) { $val="0.0"; }
        else { $val=sprintf("%.12g" , $val); }

        print "$val\n";
        $flag=0;
        next;
    }
}
```

> Example of the data which I can't read:
>   https://pastebin.com/1k51rNZc

I've tried to copy the code using what I believe is equivalent C# code, but I have to concede that I don't know what I'm doing in this regard.

Thank you.

Solution follows (not pretty)

```
 void Decompress()
 {
        var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(DataString);

        var tmp_size = bytes.Length/4;

        int idx = 0;
        List<float> mz_list = new List<float>();
        List<float> intensity_list = new List<float>();

        string Out = "I";

        foreach (object tmp in StructConverter.Unpack(tmp_size, "", bytes))
        {
            var tmp_i = StructConverter.Pack(new object[] { tmp }, false, out Out);
            var tmp_f = StructConverter.Unpack("f", tmp_i)[0];
            if (idx % 2 == 0) mz_list.Add((float)(tmp_f));
            else intensity_list.Add((float)(tmp_f));
            idx++;
        }

        X = mz_list;
        Y = intensity_list;
}
```

C# port of pack/unpack (not mine, but frankensteined by me)

```
// This is a crude implementation of a format string based struct converter for C#.
// This is probably not the best implementation, the fastest implementation, the most bug-proof implementation, or even the most functional implementation.
// It's provided as-is for free. Enjoy.

public class StructConverter
{
    static bool debug = false;

    // We use this function to provide an easier way to type-agnostically call the GetBytes method of the BitConverter class.
    // This means we can have much cleaner code below.
    private static byte[] TypeAgnosticGetBytes(object o)
    {
        if (o is int) return BitConverter.GetBytes((int)o);
        if (o is uint) return BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)o);
        if (o is long) return BitConverter.GetBytes((long)o);
        if (o is ulong) return BitConverter.GetBytes((ulong)o);
        if (o is short) return BitConverter.GetBytes((short)o);
        if (o is ushort) return BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)o);
        if (o is byte || o is sbyte) return new byte[] { (byte)o };
        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");
    }

    private static string GetFormatSpecifierFor(object o)
    {
        if (o is int) return "i";
        if (o is uint) return "I";
        if (o is long) return "q";
        if (o is ulong) return "Q";
        if (o is short) return "h";
        if (o is ushort) return "H";
        if (o is byte) return "B";
        if (o is sbyte) return "b";
        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a byte array into an array of objects based on Python's "struct.unpack" protocol.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fmt">A "struct.pack"-compatible format string</param>
    /// <param name="bytes">An array of bytes to convert to objects</param>
    /// <returns>Array of objects.</returns>
    /// <remarks>You are responsible for casting the objects in the array back to their proper types.</remarks>
    public static object[] Unpack(string fmt, byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("Format string is length {0}, {1} bytes provided.", fmt.Length, bytes.Length);

        // First we parse the format string to make sure it's proper.
        if (fmt.Length < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Format string cannot be empty.");

        bool endianFlip = false;
        if (fmt.Substring(0, 1) == "<")
        {
            if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Endian marker found: little endian");
            // Little endian.
            // Do we need to flip endianness?
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == false) endianFlip = true;
            fmt = fmt.Substring(1);
        }
        else if (fmt.Substring(0, 1) == ">")
        {
            if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Endian marker found: big endian");
            // Big endian.
            // Do we need to flip endianness?
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == true) endianFlip = true;
            fmt = fmt.Substring(1);
        }

        // Now, we find out how long the byte array needs to be
        int totalByteLength = 0;
        foreach (char c in fmt.ToCharArray())
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("  Format character found: {0}", c);
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'q':
                case 'Q':
                    totalByteLength += 8;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                case 'L':
                case 'f':
                case 'I':
                    totalByteLength += 4;
                    break;
                case 'h':
                case 'H':
                    totalByteLength += 2;
                    break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                case 'x':
                    totalByteLength += 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid character found in format string.");
            }
        }

        if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("Endianness will {0}be flipped.", (object)(endianFlip == true ? "" : "NOT "));
        if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("The byte array is expected to be {0} bytes long.", totalByteLength);

        // Test the byte array length to see if it contains as many bytes as is needed for the string.
        if (bytes.Length != totalByteLength) throw new ArgumentException("The number of bytes provided does not match the total length of the format string.");

        // Ok, we can go ahead and start parsing bytes!
        int byteArrayPosition = 0;
        List<object> outputList = new List<object>();
        byte[] buf;

        if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("Processing byte array...");
        foreach (char c in fmt.ToCharArray())
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'q':
                    outputList.Add((object)(long)BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 8;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 64-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    outputList.Add((object)(ulong)BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 8;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned 64-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    outputList.Add((object)(int)BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 4;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 32-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    outputList.Add((object)(uint)BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 4;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsignedsigned 32-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    outputList.Add((object)(short)BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 2;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 16-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    outputList.Add((object)(ushort)BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 2;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned 16-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    buf = new byte[1];
                    Array.Copy(bytes, byteArrayPosition, buf, 0, 1);
                    outputList.Add((object)(sbyte)buf[0]);
                    byteArrayPosition++;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed byte");
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    buf = new byte[1];
                    Array.Copy(bytes, byteArrayPosition, buf, 0, 1);
                    outputList.Add((object)(byte)buf[0]);
                    byteArrayPosition += 4;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned byte");
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    outputList.Add((object)(float)BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 4;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned 32-bit float.");
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    byteArrayPosition++;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Ignoring a byte");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("You should not be here.");
            }
        }
        return outputList.ToArray();
    }

    public static object[] Unpack(int len, string fmt, byte[] bytes)
    {
        string _fmt = new string('L', len);
        _fmt += fmt;

        return Unpack(_fmt, bytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an array of objects to a byte array, along with a string that can be used with Unpack.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">An object array of items to convert</param>
    /// <param name="LittleEndian">Set to False if you want to use big endian output.</param>
    /// <param name="NeededFormatStringToRecover">Variable to place an 'Unpack'-compatible format string into.</param>
    /// <returns>A Byte array containing the objects provided in binary format.</returns>
    public static byte[] Pack(object[] items, bool LittleEndian, out string NeededFormatStringToRecover)
    {

        // make a byte list to hold the bytes of output
        List<byte> outputBytes = new List<byte>();

        // should we be flipping bits for proper endinanness?
        bool endianFlip = (LittleEndian != BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);

        // start working on the output string
        string outString = (LittleEndian == false ? ">" : "<");

        // convert each item in the objects to the representative bytes
        foreach (object o in items)
        {
            byte[] theseBytes = TypeAgnosticGetBytes(o);
            if (endianFlip == true) theseBytes = (byte[])theseBytes.Reverse().ToArray();
            outString += GetFormatSpecifierFor(o);
            outputBytes.AddRange(theseBytes);
        }

        NeededFormatStringToRecover = outString;

        return outputBytes.ToArray();

    }

    public static byte[] Pack(object[] items)
    {
        string dummy = "";
        return Pack(items, true, out dummy);
    }
}
```

Comment: mzXML is Xml which is a text file.  Are you seeing text?.  If you are getting the data from a http response then it is probably GZIP and needs to be uncompressed.  See :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The problem lies in the actual data, not the XML part. I'm getting the data from our mass spectrometrist (?) as .mzXML. The actual peak data (x,y) is encoded in some weird byte code which is unreadable to me. The rest of the XML can be read easily enough. The unreadable data part is in the pastebin link (with some xml syntax around it).

Comment: The bytes maybe floating point number either single (4 bytes) or double (8 bytes).  I blocked from getting the link right now.   Won't be able to see until later today.

Comment: I'll give you a preview of the xml field containing the byte code: "<peaks precision="32" byteOrder="network" pairOrder="m/z-int">RZYAVUT+4ABFliH9RP8gAEWWQ6lE/iAARZZlWUUL4ABFlocMRQbwAE... </peaks>". There are 18976 bytes which encodes 1779 data points (probably x and y values). The "precision" is given as "32".

Comment: So 18976/1779 = ~10.  So it looks like it must be 8 bytes (single) with a separator like "\n", tab, comma, '\0'.  The data also looks like it Base 64 String.  You can use BitConverter to convert the 8 bytes to a single.

Comment: Well, I think it is more complex than that. The code (probably Perl) I've posted should be able to read the data and convert it to xy pairs of 64 bit floats. But I don't know what the different functions do and what equivalent approaches are available in C#.

Comment: A 64 bit float will not work if the numbers are 32.  It looks like 11 * 1779 = 18975 (plus one).  So group by 11 and taking first 8 in c# :  string str64 = "64 bit string here";
            byte[] decoded64 = Convert.FromBase64String(str64);
            float[] numbers = decoded64.Select((x, i) => new { num = x, index = i }).GroupBy(x => x.index / 11).Select(x => BitConverter.ToSingle(x.Select(y => y.num).Take(8).ToArray(), 0)).ToArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution follows (not pretty)

```
 void Decompress()
 {
        var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(DataString);

        var tmp_size = bytes.Length/4;

        int idx = 0;
        List<float> mz_list = new List<float>();
        List<float> intensity_list = new List<float>();

        string Out = "I";

        foreach (object tmp in StructConverter.Unpack(tmp_size, "", bytes))
        {
            var tmp_i = StructConverter.Pack(new object[] { tmp }, false, out Out);
            var tmp_f = StructConverter.Unpack("f", tmp_i)[0];
            if (idx % 2 == 0) mz_list.Add((float)(tmp_f));
            else intensity_list.Add((float)(tmp_f));
            idx++;
        }

        X = mz_list;
        Y = intensity_list;
}
```

C# port of pack/unpack (not mine, but frankensteined by me)

```
// This is a crude implementation of a format string based struct converter for C#.
// This is probably not the best implementation, the fastest implementation, the most bug-proof implementation, or even the most functional implementation.
// It's provided as-is for free. Enjoy.

public class StructConverter
{
    static bool debug = false;

    // We use this function to provide an easier way to type-agnostically call the GetBytes method of the BitConverter class.
    // This means we can have much cleaner code below.
    private static byte[] TypeAgnosticGetBytes(object o)
    {
        if (o is int) return BitConverter.GetBytes((int)o);
        if (o is uint) return BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)o);
        if (o is long) return BitConverter.GetBytes((long)o);
        if (o is ulong) return BitConverter.GetBytes((ulong)o);
        if (o is short) return BitConverter.GetBytes((short)o);
        if (o is ushort) return BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)o);
        if (o is byte || o is sbyte) return new byte[] { (byte)o };
        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");
    }

    private static string GetFormatSpecifierFor(object o)
    {
        if (o is int) return "i";
        if (o is uint) return "I";
        if (o is long) return "q";
        if (o is ulong) return "Q";
        if (o is short) return "h";
        if (o is ushort) return "H";
        if (o is byte) return "B";
        if (o is sbyte) return "b";
        throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type found");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a byte array into an array of objects based on Python's "struct.unpack" protocol.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fmt">A "struct.pack"-compatible format string</param>
    /// <param name="bytes">An array of bytes to convert to objects</param>
    /// <returns>Array of objects.</returns>
    /// <remarks>You are responsible for casting the objects in the array back to their proper types.</remarks>
    public static object[] Unpack(string fmt, byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("Format string is length {0}, {1} bytes provided.", fmt.Length, bytes.Length);

        // First we parse the format string to make sure it's proper.
        if (fmt.Length < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Format string cannot be empty.");

        bool endianFlip = false;
        if (fmt.Substring(0, 1) == "<")
        {
            if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Endian marker found: little endian");
            // Little endian.
            // Do we need to flip endianness?
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == false) endianFlip = true;
            fmt = fmt.Substring(1);
        }
        else if (fmt.Substring(0, 1) == ">")
        {
            if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Endian marker found: big endian");
            // Big endian.
            // Do we need to flip endianness?
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian == true) endianFlip = true;
            fmt = fmt.Substring(1);
        }

        // Now, we find out how long the byte array needs to be
        int totalByteLength = 0;
        foreach (char c in fmt.ToCharArray())
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("  Format character found: {0}", c);
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'q':
                case 'Q':
                    totalByteLength += 8;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                case 'L':
                case 'f':
                case 'I':
                    totalByteLength += 4;
                    break;
                case 'h':
                case 'H':
                    totalByteLength += 2;
                    break;
                case 'b':
                case 'B':
                case 'x':
                    totalByteLength += 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid character found in format string.");
            }
        }

        if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("Endianness will {0}be flipped.", (object)(endianFlip == true ? "" : "NOT "));
        if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("The byte array is expected to be {0} bytes long.", totalByteLength);

        // Test the byte array length to see if it contains as many bytes as is needed for the string.
        if (bytes.Length != totalByteLength) throw new ArgumentException("The number of bytes provided does not match the total length of the format string.");

        // Ok, we can go ahead and start parsing bytes!
        int byteArrayPosition = 0;
        List<object> outputList = new List<object>();
        byte[] buf;

        if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("Processing byte array...");
        foreach (char c in fmt.ToCharArray())
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'q':
                    outputList.Add((object)(long)BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 8;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 64-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    outputList.Add((object)(ulong)BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 8;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned 64-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    outputList.Add((object)(int)BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 4;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 32-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    outputList.Add((object)(uint)BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 4;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsignedsigned 32-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    outputList.Add((object)(short)BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 2;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed 16-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    outputList.Add((object)(ushort)BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 2;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned 16-bit integer.");
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    buf = new byte[1];
                    Array.Copy(bytes, byteArrayPosition, buf, 0, 1);
                    outputList.Add((object)(sbyte)buf[0]);
                    byteArrayPosition++;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added signed byte");
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    buf = new byte[1];
                    Array.Copy(bytes, byteArrayPosition, buf, 0, 1);
                    outputList.Add((object)(byte)buf[0]);
                    byteArrayPosition += 4;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned byte");
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    outputList.Add((object)(float)BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, byteArrayPosition));
                    byteArrayPosition += 4;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Added unsigned 32-bit float.");
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    byteArrayPosition++;
                    if (debug) Debug.WriteLine("  Ignoring a byte");
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("You should not be here.");
            }
        }
        return outputList.ToArray();
    }

    public static object[] Unpack(int len, string fmt, byte[] bytes)
    {
        string _fmt = new string('L', len);
        _fmt += fmt;

        return Unpack(_fmt, bytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an array of objects to a byte array, along with a string that can be used with Unpack.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items">An object array of items to convert</param>
    /// <param name="LittleEndian">Set to False if you want to use big endian output.</param>
    /// <param name="NeededFormatStringToRecover">Variable to place an 'Unpack'-compatible format string into.</param>
    /// <returns>A Byte array containing the objects provided in binary format.</returns>
    public static byte[] Pack(object[] items, bool LittleEndian, out string NeededFormatStringToRecover)
    {

        // make a byte list to hold the bytes of output
        List<byte> outputBytes = new List<byte>();

        // should we be flipping bits for proper endinanness?
        bool endianFlip = (LittleEndian != BitConverter.IsLittleEndian);

        // start working on the output string
        string outString = (LittleEndian == false ? ">" : "<");

        // convert each item in the objects to the representative bytes
        foreach (object o in items)
        {
            byte[] theseBytes = TypeAgnosticGetBytes(o);
            if (endianFlip == true) theseBytes = (byte[])theseBytes.Reverse().ToArray();
            outString += GetFormatSpecifierFor(o);
            outputBytes.AddRange(theseBytes);
        }

        NeededFormatStringToRecover = outString;

        return outputBytes.ToArray();

    }

    public static byte[] Pack(object[] items)
    {
        string dummy = "";
        return Pack(items, true, out dummy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]See if these numbers make any sense :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string peaks = (string)doc.Element("peaks");

            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(peaks);
            Single[] number = data.Select((x, i) => new { num = x, index = i }).GroupBy(x => x.index / 4).Select(x => BitConverter.ToSingle(x.Select(y => y.num).ToArray(), 0)).ToArray();
            PointF[] points = number.Select((x, i) => new { num = x, index = i }).GroupBy(x => x.index / 2).Select(x => new PointF(x.First().num, x.Last().num)).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a solution, though I don't quite know what I'm doing. I used a C# port of the Python struct.pack/unpack functions and then translated a Python script using those functions to C#. The pack/unpack port was missing some of the functionality, but I apparently managed to implement those myself. The numbers you posted here resemble the results I got when I was very close to solving the problem. It may have been the byte order (needs to use 'big endings' somewhere) which was the last step. Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: I was thinking the same.  If the data came from matlab complex numbers are an array of real and an array of imaginary.  So maybe the pairing is wrong.  The mzXML is open source format and I found a GITHUP project in c++.  It looks like the format is not just float numbers.  There are other Identifications in the file (not 100% sure).  Could not find the source file describing the data.  It looks like format is controlled by www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov (a government organization).

Comment: Data doesn't look like it is floating point.  See http://sashimi.sourceforge.net/schema_revision/mzXML_2.1/Doc/mzXML_2.1_tutorial.pdf